# if List a equals to List B is not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with Lists, I have two Lists, the first one's value is already set, The second one adds a number when a button has been pressed.

The code works, until this part I dont understand.
The code checks if the second List (UserList) values are equl to the first list (ButtonList) ones, if not, cleans the UserList to repeat the proccess, but, if they are equal, loads an scene and prints a message.
The problem here, is that, even if UserList equals to ButtonList, the game clears UserList.
As I can see, when it haves 8 and you add a number, the List gets clear fast.
I don't know what is happening here. Could you help me please?

```
private void Update()
    {
        string[] the_array = UserList.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
        string OrderString = string.Join(", ", the_array);
        string[] thi_array = ButtonList.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
        string OrdersString = string.Join(", ", thi_array);
        Debug.Log("ButtonList Count Is  " + ButtonList.Count + "UserList Count Is" + UserList.Count);
        print("UserList Is " + OrderString + "ButtonList Is " + OrdersString);
        if (UserList.Count == 9)
        {
            if (UserList == ButtonList)
            {
                //Sound
                BehaviourModel B = new BehaviourModel();
                B.Counter++;
                if (B.Counter < 10)
                {
                    SceneManager.LoadScene(B.SceneArray[B.Counter]);
                }
                else if (B.Counter > 10)
                {
                    SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenuScene");
                }
            }
            else if (UserList != ButtonList)
            {
                UserList.Clear();
                Debug.Log("Fail");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: UserList is, what, a `List<T>`? Comparing those will result in referential comparison: it will only return true if both objects are actually the same object. What type of objects are within the lists?

Comment: You're comparing references.

Comment: Even if the items within the lists are equal, that doesn't mean that the lists themselves are equal.

Comment: You are going to want to write a method (say `bool AreListsEqual<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) where T: IComparable`) that does the equality check you want.  Then use it.

Comment: If `UserList` and `ButtonList` are in the same order, you could use [`.SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.7.2) to compare them.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "equal".  Did you mean "the same list (reference)", "the same elements", or "the same elements in the same order"?

Answer (score 4):

To compare the contents of two lists, you can use the [`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.7.2) linq extension method. This will return true if both lists contain the same items in the same order. It may be a good idea to use an `OrderBy` clause on each list to ensure they're ordered in the same way first, and, since you're dealing with strings, you may want to use a case-insensitive comparison (that's up to you, though):

```
// Case-insensitive comparison, using OrderBy to ensure both lists are similarly ordered
if (UserList.OrderBy(u => u).SequenceEqual(ButtonList.OrderBy(b => b), 
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{ 
    // The lists contain the same contents
}
```

Comment: Good call on the `OrderBy`